# Deriving a decryption equation

Tags: modular-arithmetic, substitution-cipher

Consider a very simple symmetric block encryption algorithm, in which 32-bits blocks of plaintext are encrypted using a 64-bit key.

Encryption is defined as $C = (P\oplus K_L) \boxplus K_R$

where $C$ = ciphertext; $K$ = secret key;

$K_L$ = leftmost 32 bits of K;

$K_R$ = rightmost 32 bits of K;

$\oplus$ = bitwise exclusive or;

$\boxplus$ is addition mod $2^{32}$[image]

Show the decryption equation. That is, show the equation for P as a function of $C$, $K_L$ and $K_R$

below is my attempt, I am kinda lost.

Comment: What are you confused about?  You show an equation at the bottom; are you dissatisfied by it?  The only thing "wrong" I can immediately see is notational: using $\otimes$ for modular addition and $\ominus$ for modular subtraction, which would appear a tad inconsistent.

Comment: Looks good to me.

Answer (score 1):

The ciphertext is $C=((p \oplus K_0) + K_1) \bmod 2^K)$, so whatever the result of the Xor's operations, the ciphertext will also be 32 bits.

Since the size of plaintext is 32 bits which is similar to the size of $K_0,K_1$. So, the module operation is just an extra operation because $X \bmod 2^K$ is always $X$ for $X < 2^K$.

So, $C=(p \oplus K_0) \oplus K_1$.

To get the plaintext, perform the XOR operations in reverse order to the Ciphertext.
Plaintext, $P=(C - R_1) \oplus R_0$.

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography.SE. FYI, we have $\LaTeX$/MathJax is installed on our site. Check the edits.